# viewServiceDidTerminateWithError: Error Domain=_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={Message=Service Connection Interrupted}

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, xcode7

Mail service is showing an error in swift. The error message is **viewServiceDidTerminateWithError: Error Domain=_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={Message=Service Connection Interrupted}**. I have provided the code below for reference.

```
if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
        print("can send")
    } else {

        print("cannot send")
    }

    let mail = MFMailComposeViewController()
    mail.mailComposeDelegate = self
    mail.setSubject("DoctorVisit_\(rep_doc_visit_date[indexPath.row])")
    mail.setMessageBody("Hi, Please find attached doctor visit report. Thanks.", isHTML: false)

    let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString

    let pdfFileName = documentsPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent("report.pdf")

    if let fileData = NSData(contentsOfFile: pdfFileName) {

        print("File data loaded.")
        mail.addAttachmentData(fileData, mimeType: "application/pdf", fileName: "report")
    }
    self.presentViewController(mail, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

func mailComposeController(controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWithResult result: MFMailComposeResult, error: NSError?) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Well... You are still trying to send mail even if you have programatically determined that you cannot...